# Minecraft Plugin setMotd()

Tags: java, minecraft

I was looking for some time how to use setMotd() function, but I can't find anything useful. I've found  ServerListPingEvent http://www.javaminecraft.com/bukkitapi/org/bukkit/event/server/ServerListPingEvent.html  but I've got no idea how to use it... Maybe You could help me?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To listen to this event and, as a response, change the motd, you need a [`Listener`](http://www.javaminecraft.com/bukkitapi/org/bukkit/event/Listener.html). Define a class implementing `Listener` (let's say `FooListener`) with the following method declaration:

```
@EventHandler
public void onServerListPingEvent(ServerListPingEvent event) {
    event.setMotd("Some MOTD");
}
```

You then need to register this listener in one of your plugin class's `onLoad()` or `onEnable()` methods. Do this like so:

```
@Override
public void onLoad() { // or onEnable()
    // other stuff
    getServer().getPluginManager().registerEvents(new FooListener(), this);
}
```

If you want to colour your MOTD, look it up. You have to use the section sign (§).

Comment: Thanks it works :D but '@EventHandler', not '@EventListener'

Comment: @10anat10 Yeah, sorry. I wrote this answer from memory.